# Resize the crop of an image in google slides without distorting it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am trying to change the crop of an image using google apps script in google slides. The image gets distorted when I change the width and height of the image. And it looks like the crop properties are read-only. I was wondering if anyone here knows another way to change the size and crop without distorting the image.
https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#Page.ImageProperties

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [UpdateImagePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#UpdateImagePropertiesRequest)? It looks like `cropProperties` can be updated using this request

Comment: Thanks Kos. I just realized that the link I pasted was for the python API. And I am scripting in google-apps-script which is javascript. There doesn't seem to be an option to change crop properties. (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image) Even in the python api link from before it said that crop properties are read only.

Comment: now I see crop property is read-only. Then you only can remove image and insert new with right crop value.